# Prove that Ito process $dX_t=a(t)dt+b(t)dW_t$ is a martingale $\iff$ $a=0 dP\times dt$

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales, stochastic-integrals

We have: $W_t$ - Wiener process, $b\in M_{[0,T]}^2=\left\{f:[0,T]\times\Omega\to\mathbb{R}:\text{f is adapted}, E\left(\int_0^Tf^2(t)dt\right)<\infty\right\}$,

$a:[0,T]\times \Omega\to \mathbb{R}$ process adapted to filtration $\{F_t\}_{t\ge 0}$ such that $\int_0^TE|a(t)|dt<\infty$

Prove that Ito process $dX_t=a(t)dt+b(t)dW_t$ where $E(X_0)<\infty$ is a martingale $\iff$ $a=0 dP\times dt$

I can't find anywhere a complete proof of this theorem, written in an accessible language :(

Comment: what does "$a=0dP\times dt$" actually means? that it's equal $0$ a.s. ($dP\times dt$)?

Comment: yes exactly :))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume $(X_t)$ is a martingale, under your assumptions regarding $b$ the process $M_t=X_0+\int_0^t b dW_s$ is a martingale as well. The linear combination between martingales is again a martingale hence
$$X_t-M_t=\int_0^t a(s) ds$$ is a martingale.
This process has bounded variation and continuous sample path,  it's a well known result that a martingale satisfying this two conditions is constant, and hence the $a=0$. The other direction is immediate.

Comment: $M_t=X_0+\int_0^t b dW_s$ is a martingale because $E(X_0)<\infty$ and $X_t$ - martingale? And then process $X_t-M_t$ has bounded variation because $\int_0^TE|a(t)|dt<\infty$?